# How to make versioning on the olingo odata url

Tags: java, rest, odata, olingo

I am using Olingo OData to create my restful API. My question is if there is anyway to put versioning on the API URL? For example, we I have right now is

```
http://localhost:9090/cars
```

I am wondering if I can make it looks like

```
http://localhost:9090/v1/cars
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you use some kind of `HttpServlet` for exposing the OData service. Then, changing the URL is a matter of changing a mapping in your *web.xml* or wherever you have it.

Here is a repository where I put an example Spring Olingo app: https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/tree/master/snapgram. Mapping is done [in the main class](https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/blob/72d101873aa2d647e0076c8c947ec0f299c23d4e/snapgram/src/main/java/eu/sollers/odata/snapgram/SnapgramApplication.java#L15).